# PowerShell font changes after launching

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I'm trying to set the font of PowerShell to be Lucida Console 14, but something strange is happening.  When I launch PowerShell, the font is what I want it to be, but a second later (before the prompt appears) it changes to Raster Fonts 12x16.

I've tried the various font setting suggestions in other answers, but haven't found anything that fixes this.

At the moment, I have a shortcut on my desktop (copied from the start menu).  The Font tab is set up like this:

[image]

When I launch PowerShell from that shortcut, it starts up with the correct font, but soon changes.  Once it's changed, if I go into the Properties of the running PowerShell window, the Font tab shows:

[image]

On the running window, Defaults still shows the correct font, as set up on the shortcut.

Something appears to be changing the PowerShell font after it opens -- any ideas what it could be?

Added information:

I don't think I have a profile set up:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path $Profile
False
```

Also, I've noticed that if I manually fix the font, then run chocolatey and install something, the font sometimes changes back to Raster Fonts 12x16.

Comment: I don't know why that's happening. Maybe it is something in your profile? You could try commenting stuff out in it. But perhaps you could sidestep the problem altogether by using [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) instead of the standard console. ConEmu is worth using in any case as it is superior to the the standard console.

Comment: I don' think I have a profile set up: Test-Path $Profile returns False